# How to default form's checkbox value to null

Tags: ms-access

Is it possible to set a form's checkbox (or even a combobox) value to default to Null until the user explicitly selects a value?   The source type is Boolean, and I want to ensure that the user selects either Yes or No, and don't want it to default to No.   It seems that once the form is dirty, it wants to populate a false value.

Comment: Checkbox has a triple state property https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TripleState-Property-844BCDDE-4B1B-48AE-A375-23A53ABEA0DC, however, I find it does not work with bound checkbox. A Yes/No field cannot be null or empty string, must be yes or no, therefore control bound to Yes/No field cannot be Null or empty string.

Comment: Was thinking same thing about it being bound.  Didn't want to unbind it, but guess I'll have to do that.   Thanks.